# Symmetric matrix which rows and colomns are permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations

[Edited: WRONG QUESTION]

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that $a_{ii}=i$ and every row and colomn is a permutation of 1 to n. Denote the set of all matrices of that kind as T.

(1) If there is a symmetric matrix $A\in T$, then all matrices in $T$ are symmertric;

(2) All matrices in $T$ are symmertric $\Leftrightarrow n=2^k-1$.

It seems to be related to groups whose non-trivial elements are all order 2, but I can't find a binary operation on $T$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some definitions:

Any square table $(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ with values in $\{1,...,n\}$ is associated with the operation $\star$ defined as $i \star j = a_{ij}$. If every row and every column is a permutation, then, by definition, the set $\{1,...,n\}$ with operation $\star$ is a *quasigroup* (for convenience, we call an operation $*$ a quasigroup as well), and the corresponding table is a *latin square*.

If the latin square is symmetric, i.e., $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, then the corresponding quasigroup is called *commutative*.

If $a_{ii}=i$ for all $i$, then the latin square and the corresponding quasigroup are called *idempotent*.

(1) can be read as follows: "If there is an idempotent commutative quasigroup of order $n$, then all idempotent quasigroup of order $n$ are commutative". No, it is not true. There are many non-commutative idempotent quasigroups of any sufficiently large order $n$. So, (2) fails as well. A counterexample ($k=3$, $n=7$):
\begin{matrix}
 \color{blue}1 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 7 & 6 \\ 
 3 & \color{blue}2 & 1 & \color{red}7 & \color{red}6 & 4 & 5 \\
 2 & 1 & \color{blue}3 & \color{red}6 & \color{red}7 & 5 & 4 \\
 5 & \color{green}6 & \color{green}7 & \color{blue}4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & \color{green}7 & \color{green}6 & 1 & \color{blue}5 & 3 & 2 \\
 7 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & \color{blue}6 & 1 \\
 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & \color{blue}7 
\end{matrix}

You intuition about groups is good, but groups are much more strong objects than quasigroups (without an identity and the associative law). There is a lot of "freedom" to construct different examples of quasigroups / latin squares.